# Render inside in outlet replacing this content

Tags: view, ember.js, outlet

I'm having some difficults to render a content inside a template.

It seems to be a easy task to do, but I couldn't do anyway.

Some body can help me?

ApplicationView

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="application">
<header class="logo"><!-- ... --></header>
<nav><!-- ... --></nav>
<hr class="top" />
{{outlet}}
<hr class="bottom" />
<footer><!-- ... --><div class="clear"></div>
</footer>
</script>
```

I have the route:

```
this.resource('exibition', {path: '/exposicoes/:exibition_id'}, function() {
  this.route('artist', {path: '/artistas/:artist_id'});
});
```

Then the link `exposicoes/2` shows the exposition page with id=2 on `application outlet`, right?

The ExbitionView:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="exibition">
  <div class="exibitions">
    <h1>{{#link-to 'exibition'}}{{title}}{{/link-to}}</h1>
    <div class="left">
      <h2>Apresentação</h2>
      {{{text}}}
    </div>
    <div class="right"><h2>Artistas</h2>
      <ul>
        {{#each artist in artists}}
          <li>{{#link-to 'exibition.artist' artist}}{{artist.name}}{{/link-to}}</li>
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
    </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</script>
```

How can I make the artists links in the `ExbitionView` open in the same area where is the `{{{text}}}` replacing the content?

I tried use a outlet for this, some like:

```
<div class="left">
<h2>Apresentação</h2>
{{outlet showhere}}
</div>
```

And populate it with renderTemplate (and `disconnectOutlet` to clearup) when ExbitionView are rendered, but if the user come back from `/exibitions/2/artists/2` to `/exibitions/2` using back button or even a link on page the content doesn't show again.

Comment: Can you put it in a jsfiddle? I think you are doing something I had to do just recently, but it would be easier to visualize your progression if I could see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close to the right approach.

As you suggested, replace your `{{text}}` handlebar tag with an outlet as follows:

```
<div class="left">
    <h2>Apresentação</h2>
    {{outlet}}
</div>
```

Then, add an explicit index template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="exhibition/index">
    {{text}}
</script>
```

Along with a matching `ExhibitionIndexRoute` class to handle setting up the model for this route (with your text data in it).

And now that you have an outlet, your `artists` route will correctly render into this outlet and replace the `{{text}}`, while the `ExhibitionIndexRoute` will correctly repopulate the data when you use the back button.

Comment: Amazing gravityplanx! You save my day!

Just an observation, it's necessary `this.modelFor('exibition');` to get the parent model on `ExibitionIndexRoute`.

thanks a lot people!